# What is use Error Constant files in java?

Tags: java

while writing some code , I was thinking is this the best way to define errors in the code itself or it is better to make it in a separate file like error constant file.

Comment: you need to expand your question, it hardly makes any sense, none of us know what "error" you are talking about.

Comment: What errors? Errors made by some user giving wrong input or errors (exceptions) in code?

Comment: Too low details. Seems (to some degree) You think in "C" convention. Error code have strong criticism in OOP, and exception is accepted way.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if possible you can externalize the error messages in a properties files.This will be  helpful in case of internationalization of your application (one properties file per language). It is also easier to modify an error message, and it won't need any re-compilation of the Java sources.It will be useful when you are managing lot of error message.For small number may be significance will not visible.

Or you can use enum to store error code and description

```
public enum Exception {
  EXCEPTION1(0, "A  error has occured."),
  EXCEPTION2(1, "SOME MESSGE.");

  private final int errorCode;
  private final String description;

  private Exception(int errorCode, String description) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
    this.description = description;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
     return description;
  }

  public int getErrorCode() {
     return errorCode;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return errorCode + ": " + description;
  }
}
```